# Erro ao utilizar monolog: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Monolog\Logger' not found

Tags: php, log

Tentei utilizar monolog na minha aplicação, porém, depois da instalação feita de acordo com a [documentação](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md#installation), eu tento importar e utilizar, mas vem uma mensagem de erro informando que não foi possível encontraá-lo.

```
<?php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

// Create the logger
$logger = new Logger('my_logger');
```

Utilizei apenas o código acima.

Comment: Está utilizando o Composer ou alguma outra ferramenta de autoload?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Utilizo o Composer

Comment: E o arquivo de autoload foi inserido no projeto em algum momento?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Sim sim, está dentro da pasta 'Vendor'

Comment: Inserido no sentido de dar `include` ou `require` neste arquivo. Desculpe-me caso souber usar o Composer e essas perguntas parecerem básicas, mas é que o erro parece estar em o PHP não conseguir carregar a classe e a ausência do `include` faria todo sentido.

Comment: Pode ser que o básico me ajude, pq não uso muito php, então não conheço muito. Não, o arquivo autoload não foi carregado, imaginei que só utilizar o `use Monolog\Logger;` ja era o bastante para que funcionasse

Comment: Agora sim funcionou. Coloca uma resposta dizendo pra mim realizar um require no autoload. @AndersonCarlosWoss

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme discutido nos comentários, buscando entender melhor o problema, a falta do carregamento do arquivo `autoload` do Composer faz com que o PHP não saiba como buscar as classes. Composer faz mágica, mas nem tanto. Após a instalação, deve existir um diretório `vendor` em sua aplicação, com as dependências de projeto. Antes de usá-las, faça a inserção do arquivo `autoload`, no início de cada arquivo:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler;

// Create the logger
$logger = new Logger('my_logger');
```

O arquivo `vendor/autoload.php` é o padrão do Composer, que faz toda a mágica acontecer.

> **Nota**: o arquivo `autoload` deve ser incluído uma vez a cada requisição tratada no PHP. Isto é, se sua aplicação faz requisições a diversos arquivos PHP, o `require autoload` deve estar presente em todos eles. Se ela for baseada em alguma arquitetura, tal como MVC, em que todas as requisições são tratadas em apenas um arquivo, basta, apenas, colocar nele para estar acessível em todo o projeto.